# How to test if a conda environmnt exists and matches the contents of a yml environment file in shell

Tags: shell, conda

I am running some bash scripts that submit sbatch scripts after doing some stuff and I want to check if the conda environment requierd for the tools in the sbatch script to work exists and then that this named conda environment matches the contents of a conda environment yml file.

So essentially this:

```
test ! -d ~/miniconda3/envs/fungal-hybrid-assembly || echo "Conda environment does not exist. Initialising conda environment......" && conda create fungal-hybrid-assembly.yml
```

But testing that the fungal-hybrid-assembly environment actually contains the correct packages rather than it just existing.

Comment: This is a bit underspecified. What are the criteria for an environment to "*match*" a YAML? Is presence of the package sufficient (i.e., works across platforms), or do builds matter? What if the env is a superset of the YAML (has extra packages)? If you want exact match, then `diff $(conda env export -n your_env) some.yaml` would be a strict test.

Comment: I did indeed mean exact match as I am using it for version controlling. Thank you

Comment: After trying the above, this code unfortunatly does not work.